# How can I compare two sound files if they have the same pitch and text in Unity Android App?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I'm creating a japanese learning app, and I have a portion there where they need to repeat the sentence given to them. Is there other neat way to do comparison with the audio file and user input? instead of just passing it to a speech-to-text?
I do need the pitch comparison.